# Customize 'find' logic in JPA repositories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following question for the community: is there any way to customize the 'find' logic for all my JPA repositories?

For example, I would like my custom 'find' logic to be invoked automatically everytime a method containing the word 'find' is created in my JPA repositories (findAll, findById, findOne, ..).

I'm trying to follow the official documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository) but I don't understand if I'm doing something wrong or if it's not possible to implement what I have in mind with this straregy.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you mean by "customize"?

Comment: Sure. I was wondering if it's possible to mix the power of the derived query methods in Spring with the possibility to use custom logic each time a derived query method starts with 'find'. Let's say the result of my new 'find' would be a join of the requested entity with a fixed table,I would like for example my existing legacy derived query method 'findProductByCode' to use this new logic for the 'find' part and then executing the rest (ProductByCode) as before (to avoid re-writing it from scratch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the use of `Spring AOP` (I suggest you read the docs). When using annotations, your pointcut expression (inside an aspect) would look like so:

```
@Pointcut("execution(*org.yourpackage.repositories.*.find*(..))")
public void customFind() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @k-wasilewski, Spring AOP is a valid way but I was trying to use a custom repository factory because I would like to mix the power of Spring derived query method and the possibility to override part of its logic with a complex sql query. Let's say my new find logic is 'select e Entity e inner join ...'.I would like to use thid new 'find' logic for all my derived query methods containing the word 'find' (for example 'find'+ByLastName, 'find'+ById, ..). My goal is to introduce a new feature in legagy code without refactoring all the existing queries generated via derived query methods.